# Automate search from database data into text field using php

Tags: javascript, php, json, mysqli

I'm trying to automate my textfield of webform with auto search from database, where I have been trying it from many days. What I see is I get all the data which I typed but not with the data in the database. Can anyone help me out of this?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input.module_nbr').module_nbr({
            name: 'module_nbr',
            remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
            limit : 3
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('','', '', '') OR die(mysqli_connect_error());
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
    $query=mysqli_query("select module_nbr from module_master where module_nbr LIKE '%{$key}%'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));
    {
        $array[] = $row['module_nbr'];
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

This will be a piece of code where I'm going to implement it in almost all fields of my form to reduce typing to the user.

Comment: What is `module_nbr`?

Comment: What is `%QUERY`, because I think its not sending any data in the key parameter, because of which it will return same data ..

Comment: module_nbr will the column name